# Is there a way to close all the explorer windows but the active one?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Let's say I have multiple explorer windows open, is there a way to close all but the one currently active?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you click and drag one window and shake it quickly it will minimize all other windows.

Comment: @JaredT Yep, thanks, I read about it when looking for a solution to this problem. But indeed, it's not exactly what I am looking for. "Minimizing" is not "closing", and it affects also all windows from other applications.